# How to build a large 2d array out of many smaller 2d arrays

Tags: c#

I am trying to work towards a

```
512 x 512 (262144 elements)
```

I currently have a

```
List<double[,]> data;
```

Dimensions are:

```
4096 x [8 , 8] (262144 elements)
```

The 2d array I am working towards is ***square***.

```
List<List<float>> newList = new List<List<float>(); //working towards
```

I have tried something along the lines of:

```
for (int i = 0; i < Math.Sqrt(data.Count); i++ ) {
    List<float> row = new List<float>();
    foreach (double[,] block in data) {
        for (int j = 0; j < 8; j++) {
            row.Add(block[i,j]); //i clearly out of range
        }
    }
    newList.Add(row);
}
```

What I was trying to do there was to brute force my way and add up every row (which is 8 in length) and then add the large rows to the newList.

Comment: You really should think of this as mapping 3 coordinates to 2 coordinates.  The 3 are the index of the arrays in your list and the 2 indexes on those arrays.  And the 2 you are mapping to are the indexes of the outer and inner lists.  So, can you define where in your list of lists you would want to put `data[5][2,3]`?

Comment: data[5][2,3] would be in 8 * 5 = 40 + 3  + 1= 44th element of the 3rd row unless I made a math mistake.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you can do that in the following way

```
var newList = new List<List<float>>();

for (int i = 0; i < 512; i++)
{
    var innerList = new List<float>();
    for (int j = 0; j < 512; j++)
    {
        int x =(i/8)*64 + (j/8);
        int y = i % 8;
        int z = j % 8;
        innerList.Add(data[x][y,z]);
    }

    newList.Add(innerList);
}
```

Basically you have 64x64 of your 8x8 blocks.  So the (i,j) coordinate of the larger 512x512 structure translate in the following ways.  First to determine the 8x8 block you have to figure out the row and column of the 64x64 structure of blocks by dividing the i and j by the size of the block (8)  then you multiply the row (i/8) by the number of block in a row (64) and add the column (j/8).  For the y and z it's simpler because you know that its just a matter of the remainder of i and j when divided by 8 (i%8) and (j%8).